# how to text a clickable phone number including extension on android messages

Tags: android, sms, wait, phone-call

How do I text a clickable phone number that includes the wait to dial extension on android messages?

on iOS I would simply type 8008008000; 123456# and I can even text that to iOS from android and it works, but when I text that to other android phones, the full link gets broken and android only dial the number from the message, requiring going back to the message to copy the extension for paste into dialer of active call.

I want the wait functionality, not the pause function.
I can create contacts in android like 8008008000; 123456# and they operate as desired, the solution I am after will not include creating the contact then sharing the contact.

I need to know what to type in and hit send, and it work for the recipient as desired.

Comment: Hey @johnwayne have you managed to figure out a solution to this problem? I'm dealing with the same at the moment and trying to find a way to solve this.

Comment: @Gligor I have not.

Comment: Bummer! Neither have I :)

Answer (score 0):

typically it would be a comma (8008008000,123456#  with NO spaces.) but its been my experience that .5 seconds (,) is insufficient for the number to be picked up and the IVR to register. a full second is more common, (8008008000,,123456# ) however, Android doesnt seem to parse a double-comma.